# How do you change the value of a defined colour?

Tags: android, resources

I have created a custom library which countains layout files and resource files.

In it I have created a colors.xml file which contains the following

```
<resources>
    <color name="dialog.background">#000000</color>
    <color name="dialog.widget">#dd393f44</color>
    <color name="dialog.text">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

those are used by my layout files to create dialogs with specific colours.

I wish to make it so that the application that uses this library can send a message to it when it starts to define those three colours.

Other than creating the dialog from the layout files and then changing each widget's colors programmatically, is there a way to replace the above mentioned colours with the one the application provides?

thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38486167/4504191

Comment: thank you, this seems to be what I want